# Karate not supporting JSON Path

Tags: karate

I have a JSON path, say $[advertiserId]  and this evaluates to

```
[
  "001E000000yBFskIAG"
]
```

using tool https://jsonpath.com/? .

However, the equivalent Karate syntax does not work:

And match response[*].advertiserId == '001E000000yBFskIAG'

It does not recogize this path.

If I have JSON:

```
{
"advertiserId":"someID"
}
```

Then

And match response[*].advertiserId == 'someID'

should work. Karate ought to be able to support basic JSON matching.

Answer (score 0):

Karate is stricter - if there is JsonPath "wildcard" e.g. `*` or `..` the result will *always* be an array. Maybe jsonpath.com converts a single element array to the value for convenience - but we will never do that.

The below works:

```
* def response = [{ advertiserId: '001E000000yBFskIAG' }]
* match response[*].advertiserId == ['001E000000yBFskIAG']
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, that is helpful. I still think this is a horrible limitation on the part of Karate,but I guess any work around better than no workaround.